# Find sets of points, where function from one topological space to another is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We have got two functions :

$f(x,y) = (2x,y)$

$g(x,y) = (x+1,y) $

They are transormations from one topological space to another ( from $ (\mathbb{R^2}, \tau')$ to $ (\mathbb{R^2}, \tau'')$ ), where $ \tau'$ is topology induced by rail metric and ,$\tau''$ ais topology  induced by river metric. We need to find sets of points, where the function is continuous.

So, there'll be 4 possibilites  for every function :

river into river

river into rail

rail into river

rail into rail

**RAIL METRIC** - $$d(x,y) =\begin{cases} \lVert x-y\rVert & \text{if }x,y\text{ and }0\text{ lie on the same line,}\\ \lVert x\rVert + \lVert y\rVert & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}$$ where $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is the standard Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^2.$

**RIVER METRIC** - $$d(x,y) =\begin{cases} \lvert x_2-y_2\rvert & \text{if }x_1 = y_1,\\ \lvert x_2\rvert + \lvert x_1 - y_1\rvert + \lvert y_2\rvert & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Could anyone help me to understand idea of problem like this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with "rail metric" or "river metric." Can you include those definitions in your question? (Also, it seems that you should have $\Bbb R^2$ in both cases, rather than $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: What's the definition of "rail" and "river" metrics?

Comment: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~svanstri/Files/ma222.pdf They are called "French railway metric" and "Jungle river metric"

Comment: My compliments on an interesting question! I have to head out the door shortly, but if it remains unanswered when I return this evening, I will take a crack at it. I *will* say, though, that it would be to your benefit to know what the open balls in the two metrics look like. Note that they will differ in shape, depending on where they are "centered" and what the "radius" is.

Comment: I do know how they look like. At first we have to ascertain if transformations are continuous ( check whether or not preimage of some set in an image belongs to topology in domain )

Comment: $f$ from rail into rail is cont. all over $\mathbb{R^2}$. From river into river as well. from river into rail and from rail into river $f$ is continuous all over X axis and Y axis. $g$ rail into rail is cont. in $\mathbb{R}|{(0,0)}$, river into river in $\mathbb{R^2}$, rail into river in X axis and Y axis, river into rail all over line $x=-1$. It's only my intuition I don't know formal proof

Answer (score 0):

Some HINTS:

1. Assume that $a\ne 0$, and let $p=\langle a,b\rangle$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $p_n=\langle a,b+2^{-n}\rangle$; then $\langle p_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to p$ in the river metric. Does $\langle g(p_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converge to $g(p)$ in the rail metric? Does $\langle f(p_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converge to $f(p)$ in the rail metric?
2. Assume further that $b\ne 0$, let $m=\frac{b}a$, and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $q_n=\langle a+2^{-n},m(a+2^{-n})\rangle$; then $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to p$ in the rail metric. Does $\langle g(q_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converge to $g(p)$ in the river metric? Does $\langle f(q_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converge to $f(p)$ in the river metric? What if $b=0$?

It may be useful to note that all four image sequences converge to $p$ in the usual metric on the plane.